# How to combine several file parts (Blobs) to the original file after ajax upload with unix cat command?

Tags: php, upload, exec, blob, cat

I created an uploader script which can upload large files because it splits it into blobs. But I figured out that using PHP's fopen and fwrite won't work for putting the parts back together again (maybe a memory thing).

I figured out that there is a unix command cat that could put it together (http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-appleosx-bsd-cat-command-examples/)

But the question is: How can I select all fileparts and put it together in one PHP exec command?

I think the syntax would be kinda like this but I have no idea how to select all the parts:

```
exec('cat "'.$all_my_parts.'" >> "' . $original_filename.'"');
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on your issues with using PHP to do it?

Comment: Because after the upload a batchjob is starting and everything shall be automatic. So after the last part is uploaded the restoring script is fired via ajax call. How else to do?

Comment: I mean the `fopen and fwrite won't work for putting the parts back together again` part.

Comment: I don't remember anymore. But for big files it just didn't work. Was a timeout or memory error. Then someone suggested to work with cat because that works for sure for large files.